# Totals on combo stacked bar/cumulative line chart in tableau

Tags: excel, tableau-api, stacked-chart

[This is ultimately what I need in but in Tableau](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghc6Z.png)So I'm fairly new to Tableau and as I feared something extremely simple in Excel is proving to be rather complex in this new software.

I have a monthly running stacked bar chart of the closeouts by team(colored) and a line demonstrating the overall cumulative count of closeouts since the program started.

How do I simply add the total amount per month to a graph already using the Dual Axis feature for the cumulative running total?  Thank you!

[This is what I have so far - Closeouts Combo Stacked Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awMgm.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might have the label set to Line Ends. To check this do the following. Go to the marks card section on the left under filters. You will have three marks cards because of the dual axis, All, Bar and Line. Select the line card and click the label box. In there you can see if this is set to Line Ends under marks to label. Change this to All if so and see if that works.

Comment: So the thing is I want that Line Ends total number up top showing the cumulative total of 6,372 achieved to date. 

I also want to show the Monthly *total count* as well as the *individual team count(which i currently have). I want that total count per month to appear above the bars, not along the line. Thank you though.

Comment: Is this more what you need then? http://www.vizwiz.com/2015/02/stacked-bar-total.html

Comment: Not quite. I attached a new photo of what I need. I think the issue is that I'm already using a dual axis for my cumulative count, and getting that total on top of the stacked bar(as well as the sub totals by team within the stacked bar) is proving quite difficult.  I think maybe the reference line angle is the way to go but when I try that nothing appears...